# How do I extend Python with C?

Tags: python, c

I have been doing a lot of reading on this subject and am having a lot of trouble wrapping my brain around how this needs to happen.

What I want to do is have a function:

```
int Add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

And be able to call it from my Python scripts. How do I do this?

Comment: read this step-by-step tutorial; does it answer your question?  http://csl.sublevel3.org/C-functions-from-Python/

Comment: also see ctypes: http://richizo.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/calling-c-functions-inside-python/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way by far is using the [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) module, which will allow you to call functions in C libraries directly from Python. Once you have your C function compiled as a library, you can write something to the effect of:

```
# Load ctypes, and your library
from ctypes import *
mylib = CDLL("mylibrary.so")

# Declare the function's prototype. This isn't strictly required.
mylib.Add.argtypes = [c_int, c_int]
mylib.Add.restype = c_int

# Call it!
result = mylib.Add(123, 456)
```

Comment: +1 for ctypes.  It's my default choice for c extensions, unless some other consideration drives one of the other options.

Comment: ctypes is also a good choice if you plan to run your code on PyPy.

Answer (score 7):

The proper way is to [write an extension module](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html).  But if you're doing simple stuff (such as adding two integers) than can be done independently of Python, you can just write a regular shared library in C (which would be a DLL on Windows), and load it using the [ctypes module](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html).

For example:

```
// C code
int Add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

Compile that like this:

```
gcc add.c -fPIC -shared -o libadd.so
```

Then use it in Python like this:

```
import ctypes
libadd = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libadd.so')
libadd.Add.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int]
libadd.Add.restype = ctypes.c_int

print libadd.Add(42, 1)  # Prints 43
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to go about it.  The classic Python C API is a little complicated, but is the source of all Python.  You can get started with: [A Whirlwind Excursion through Python C Extensions](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/whirlext.html).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [pyrex](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/Pyrex/)? It lets your write in a python-similar syntax that will then be compiled to a C extension module.

The [quick-quide](http://ldots.org/pyrex-guide/) should get you started easily and is full of real world examples.

Comment: This is cool to get a performance boost, but won't help you use existing C code from Python.

Comment: (The OP never stated that he wants to do that). You're wrong; you can create pythonic pyrex wrappers around existing C code (it is exactly what is done in the quick guide with the CUPS driver).

Comment: I know the OP didn't state that; most details are probably omitted from the question.  Also, I'm not saying that this answer is no good.  It's just that other tools (e.g. [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/python/doc/)) make that use case easier.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to implement part of your code in C, I'd recommend using [cython](http://cython.org). For example, you could write your `Add` function like so:

```
cpdef int Add(int x, int y):
    return x+y
```

And then use cython to compile it into a module you can import into your code.